# How to get url ID in PHP? (for mysql_query UPDATE)

Tags: php, mysql

I want to add an edit button for a script called spiral url, but the problem is that I can't get the URL id.  This is what I've tried:

```
/** get url id **/
$id = isset($_GET['id']) ? $_GET['id'] : '';
@mysql_query("UPDATE short_urls SET long_url = 'test' WHERE url_id = '".$id."' LIMIT 1");
```

What am I doing wrong?

Also I emailed the author and his response:

> "I recommend you post on Stackoverflow - https://stackoverflow.com/.
>   I would love to help you but I don't see what you are doing wrong. I'm still learning PHP as well."

Comment: You're opening yourself to SQL injection attacks by not escaping user input before putting it into a query string.

Comment: What is the url you call to launch this script ? As a side note, you're here wide open to SQL Injection. Maybe could you use PDO prepared statement ?

Comment: Also, don't use the error suppressor @ before mysql_query()

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. You're wide open to SQL injection attacks.
2. You're supressing errors with the `@` operator. **NEVER** suppress errors
3. You're not checking the return value of mysql_query(), which returns a boolean FALSE on failure.

Scrap that code and use this:

```
if (!isset($_GET['id'])) {
    die("missing query parameter");
}
$id = intval($_GET['id']);
if ($id === '') {
    die("Invalid query parameter");
}
$sql = "UPDATE short_urls SET long_url = 'test' WHERE url_id=$id LIMIT 1";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
if ($result === FALSE) {
    die("Mysql error: " . mysql_error() . $sql);
}
```

Note that I'm assuming that the `id` parameter is numeric. If it's not, then remove the intval() stuff.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the value of `$_GET['id']` actually has a value. Your URL will look something like `http://myurl.com/index.phtml?id=yourvalue`. You can do this by doing a:

```
print "id=".$_GET['id'];
```

Also, whenever doing a query, please be sure to escape any and all variables that can be manipulated by the user. Without doing this, you're opening yourself up to SQL injection attacks.

mysql_real_escape_string - http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php

```
@mysql_query("UPDATE short_urls SET long_url = 'test' WHERE url_id = '".mysql_real_escape_string($id)."' LIMIT 1");
```

Answer (score 0):

If the url is like this: `domain.com/something.php?id=65`

`$_GET['id']` should be equal to `65`

if there is no `id` there then when you try to access `$_GET['id']` you will get an error.

Also try removing the `@` symbol (that suppresses PHP warning).

And you are waaaay open to [bobby-tables](http://xkcd.com/327/)

Also (side note), get a new developer who knows what they are doing ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the url

http://www.somewebsite.com?id=56&other_car=test

specifically for the "?" after the end of the url and also check all the parts are broken up by the ampersand.

failing that you can view all of your available get array variables by

```
print_r($_GET);
```